# Why my VBA code doesn't run the macros called

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with this code, doesn't run the sub I'm calling and tells me that xlApp is not defined…

The thing is that I needed to separate each “Sub” because the sendkeys didn't work as I wanted when I use 1 sub to execute it all, so I split it.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Const slp As Variant = 1000

Sub Main()
    Dim mywb As Workbook: Set mywb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xlApp As Application
    
     Set wb = Nothing
     Set xlApp = Nothing
    
Call WhichOne
Call Unprotect

End Sub
Sub WhichOne()

    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "K:\Drive RMB\RMB Chantier\7_Sous Traitance\ISF CHRONO SOUS-TRAITANT"
    Dim strTempFile As String: strTempFile = strFolder & "aaOWB.bas"
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim xpath As String
    
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
        xFileDialog.Title = "Choisir un fichier"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
       xFile = Dir(xStrPath)
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xFile)
        xlApp.Visible = True
    
End Sub
Sub Unprotect()

        With Application
        .SendKeys "%{F11}", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "^r", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "792432700", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep slp
        End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) When you run the code in Excel you don't need xlApp, just use `Application` as you did in the 'unprotect' sub 2) you have to define `wb` in your `WhichOne` sub not in the `Main` sub - or use `wb1` which is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Valid code with Ike suggestions:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Const slp As Variant = 1000

Sub Main()
    Dim mywb As Workbook: Set mywb = ThisWorkbook
    
    
     
    
Call WhichOne
Call Unprotect

End Sub
Sub WhichOne()

    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "K:\Drive RMB\RMB Chantier\7_Sous Traitance\ISF CHRONO SOUS-TRAITANT"
    Dim strTempFile As String: strTempFile = strFolder & "aaOWB.bas"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim xpath As String
    
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
        xFileDialog.Title = "Choisir un fichier"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
       xFile = Dir(xStrPath)
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(xFile)
        Application.Visible = True
    
End Sub
Sub Unprotect()

        With Application
        .SendKeys "%{F11}", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "^r", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "792432700", True
        Sleep slp
        .SendKeys "~", True
        Sleep slp
        End With
        
End Sub
```